# Inserting a paper with one's request in between the stones of the western wall

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, kotel-western-wall

I once heard a rabbi say that there is an ancient custom (i.e. *minhag*) to insert a paper with ones *bakashos* (requests) in between the stones of the western wall.

1. Where is the *source* of this *minhag*?
2. Is it a *minhag* or *halachah*?

Comment: Since the old post didn't address this, I wonder how meaningful the act of placing prayers into crevices can be since "The Wall" is known to be part of the outer wall of the temple compound, not physically part of the temple. Also, the eastern wall that we observe today is actually an later addition to the original wall that is still underground.

Comment: Any prayer is meaningful to the person who prays sincerely. Hashem hears prayer - all types.

Comment: It certainly isn't halacha